How to access RDS MySQL database using Nodejs with IAM authentication
Currently using Nodejs, I connect to RDS MySQL database using below approach,
const mysql = require("mysql");
const environment = require("../core/environment/environment");

const connection = mysql.createPool({
                                      host: environment.mysql.host,
                                      port: environment.mysql.port,
                                      user: environment.mysql.user,
                                      password: environment.mysql.password,        // is there a way to avoid it
                                      connectionLimit: 10
                                    });

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Connected to database.');
});

connection.end();

The problem with above approach is I have to expose/reveal/store password in the environment file which I don't want.
I recently came across this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.html which allows to access DB using IAM authentication without using password but it doesn't describe any way to deal with Nodejs platform. However, it has other platform articles eg Python,.NET etc but not Nodejs.
I googled other ways out but can't seem to find any reference how to access RDS in Nodejs app without password.
How can I achieve it ?

You can use rds-signer package (part of aws-sdk). This should help you to obtain temporary tokens using your IAM Default config or IAM role for secure connections to your RDS instance.
const signer = new Signer({
  /**
   * Required. The hostname of the database to connect to.
   */
  hostname: "db.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  /**
   * Required. The port number the database is listening on.
   */
  port: 8000,
  /**
   * Required. The username to login as.
   */
  username: "user1",
  /**
   * Optional. The AWS credentials to sign requests with. Uses the default credential provider chain in not specified.
   */
  credentials: fromNodeCredentialProvider(),
  /**
   * Optional. The region the database is located in. Uses the region inferred from the runtime if omitted.
   */
  region: "us-east-1",
  /**
   * Optional. The SHA256 hasher constructor to sign the request.
   */
  sha256: HashCtor,
});

const token = await signer.getAuthToken();

Reference:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-rds-signer/

does it mean that I have to use this generated token  as  password : token while connecting to RDS ? OR Do you have any example of how to use this token ? I can't see example in your link.

You can help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78454898/generate-auth-token-using-aws-sdk-v2-and-nodejs-to-connect-to-rds-mysql-database

@micronyks Yes you will need to use this Token as a password. You can use your same code. Just create token before connecting to DB

How to refresh that time to time as to update global connection

I am using NestJS and able to connect to a PostgreSQL database using AWS IAM with an auth token. However, the token only lasts for 15 minutes, so I need to generate a new one. The datasource created when the app starts becomes invalid after 15 minutes. How can I fix this?
